# Can i bind my extension to Ctrl-S without disrupting saving?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'd like to make Brackets.io extension that would both save active file and execute  my code on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

I tried to use `command-line-shortcuts` extension to do that but it throws error

```
/command/KeyBindingManager.js:749 Cannot assign Ctrl-S to 
extension.commandline.run.0. It is already assigned to file.save
```

So is it possible to assign two 'actions' to one key binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be [opened issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12567) on Brackets github. So for now it can't be done.